# Please check my proof by using Arbitrariness of ε

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

**Proposition**
Let $s>0.$ $\forall \varepsilon>0$ , $(s-\varepsilon)^2<2 \Rightarrow s^2 \leq 2$ .
**My proof**
proof by contradiction. 
Assume that $\forall \varepsilon>0$ , $(s-\varepsilon)^2<2 $ and $ s^2 > 2$ .
Let $\varepsilon = 2s>0$ , then $(s-\varepsilon)^2=s^2<2 $ .
However, it contradicts the fact that $ s^2 > 2$ . $\square$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Looks good, but as a subtlety, a proof by contradiction would assume that *there exists* some $\varepsilon$ s.t. $(s-\varepsilon)^2<2$ and $s^2>2$, rather than assuming that such does not hold for *all* $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Graviton That's not correct; the OP is trying to prove $P\Rightarrow Q$ by assuming, for contradiction, "$P$ and not $Q$" - which is a valid way to go about this. The way you propose (assuming existence of such a $\varepsilon$ and that $s^2 > 2$) is not a correct way to start a proof by contradiction of this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems ok.

If $\epsilon=2s$, then $(s-\epsilon)^2 = (s-2s)^2=(-s)^2=s^2<2$ which contradicts $s^2 \le 2$.

However, I think the statement is not that useful because we can't find such an $s$. Let $\epsilon = ks$, where $k>0$.

$$(s-\epsilon)^2=(1-k)^2s^2$$ but $k$ can be arbitrary large.